# Date format at noUiSlider tooltips

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I'm trying to use noUiSlider at my project but I am not able to apply the date format inside the tooltips. I just got it at outside divs.

Take a look at this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vvgr74v2/).

```
noUiSlider.create(dateSlider, {
    behaviour: 'tap',
    connect: true,
    tooltips: [ true, true ],
    range: {
        min: timestamp('2016-06-01') + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        max: timestamp(date)
    },
    step: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    start: [timestamp(previousMonth), timestamp(date)]
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `format` option:

```
// Move formatting code into a function
function toFormat ( v ) {
    return formatDate(new Date(v));
}

// Add a formatter to the slider
format: { to: toFormat, from: Number }

// You can then directly use the value in the update function
dateValues[handle].innerHTML = values[handle];
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/vvgr74v2/1/).